# How to make video with a scrolling graphic?

Tags: video-editor, youtube

I want to make video like this

I am noob in video making...give some direction to start

Answer (score 4):

You create the whole graphic as a still image - for the above, likely a 1080 x 28000 px image to start with.

Then I'd import the image into either Premiere or After Effects based on what you're more comfortable using.

Then you set a keyframe on the initial position of the graphic - then move the graphic horizontally to the left, all the way to the end, move your timeline to the end of the project and drop another keyframe for the ending position.

Then you'll likely have to tinker with the project length and keyframe positions to fine tune the timing of the virtual camera pan.

There's a ton of tutorials available to accomplish a simple task like animating an image: